# Авторизовался через Chrome/Firefox, а парсеру выдает страницу авторизации

Tags: python, авторизация, python-3.x, парсер

Пишу парсер на питоне.

Нужные мне страницы видит только авторизованный пользователь. Я авторизовался через chrome/firefox, но парсеру выдают страницу авторизации.

Куда смотреть?

Comment: зависит от сайта, где-то достаточно [заголовок передать](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4188709/4279), где-то cookies, где-то даже автоматизация браузера, используя selenium webdriver или phantomjs, не поможет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что скорее всего ваш парсер не поддерживает авторизацию. То что вы вошли на сайт через браузер, ничего не значит, ибо браузер и ваш парсер - разные приложения.

Для того чтобы ваш парсер мог использовать данные браузера для входа, их ему необходимо передать в виде куки. Просмотреть какие куки ставит сайт можно в консоли разработчика Chrome (Ctrl+I):

[image: Консоль разработчика]

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете посмотреть для python библиотеку mechanize. Там есть  примеры с авторизацией и дальнейшей работы с сайтом. Описано просто, примеры простые. Я думаю сложностей не возникнет.